# Maven Build War File Contains Errors

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have Spring MVC application and below is the structure attached

[image]

The problem I am facing is whenever my maven builds the war file then it does not deploy properly on the tomcat.But when I export manually then it runs absolutely fine.

I compared both the war files after extraction, there's a difference that all of the XML files are not included in the WEB-INF folder, although there is a classes folder present. Can anyone help?
This is a snippet of my pom.xml file

```
    <sourceDirectory>src/</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <resource>
                    <directory>/src/main/webapp</directory>
                </resource>
                <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                <warName>hfcl</warName>
                <!-- <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml> <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml> -->
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webXml>WebContent\WEB-INF\web.xml</webXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Looks like you could flip `failOnMissingWebXml` to "true" to narrow down the problem further.

Comment: I tried doing "true" also but of no use.

Comment: Please removed windows paths separator use "/" instead in Maven pom file...If you like to omit `failOnMissingWebXml` simply use a most recent version of maven-war-plugin...

Comment: Tried this also, the same issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe maven filters out the xml files. Adding the resources tag under the build tag like this:

```
 <build>
    <resources>

        <resource>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/xml</directory>
        </resource>
    </resources>
<plugin>
 ....
</build>
```

Comment: My xml files are not in src/main. Then what to do?

Comment: One suggestion is to move your webapp sources inside src/main/webapp

Comment: Tried that also but of no use.